# Associating sprites in a container - Pixi.js

Tags: javascript, animation, pixi.js

Let's suppose that I have 2 classes which look alike:

```
//one class
    function classA() {
    var texture = PIXI.Texture.fromImage("someImage");
    PIXI.extras.TilingSprite.call(this, texture, 224, 219);

    this.position.x = 0;
    this.position.y = 0;
    this.tilePosition.x = 0;
    this.tilePosition.y = 0;
    }

    classA.constructor = classA;
    classA.prototype = Object.create(PIXI.extras.TilingSprite.prototype);

//another class
    function classB() {
    var texture = PIXI.Texture.fromImage("anotherImage");
    PIXI.extras.TilingSprite.call(this, texture, 36, 42);

    this.position.x = 0;
    this.position.y = 0;
    this.tilePosition.x = 0;
    this.tilePosition.y = 0;
    }

    classB.constructor = classB;
    classB.prototype = Object.create(PIXI.extras.TilingSprite.prototype);
```

In another file, I create 1 instance of classA and 3 from classB and add all of them in a container:

```
container = new PIXI.Container();
renderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(224, 219, {view:document.getElementById("some-canvas")});

a = new classA();
container.addChild(a);
b1 = new classB();
container.addChild(b1);
b2 = new classB();
container.addChild(b2);
b3 = new classB();
container.addChild(b3);
```

I wanted to associate in some way the classB to classA, so that I don't need to create 3 instances of classB everytime I create 1 instance of classA (in another words, I would like do perform one addChild() function per class instantiation). Is that possible?

Comment: Though I'm not sure if I'm really answering the correct question in my answer. Since I do not understand the statement: "so that I don't need to create 3 instances of classB everytime I create 1 instance of classA". Since if you do this same operation multiple times, you could just separate it to it's own function. But putting the addChild inside constructor is imo. still a bad choice... Or you can make addChildren function, which iterates through an array and adds all the children to the given container.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to make sure I understand what you are trying to achieve. You basically want to switch the container.addChild function to be done inside constructor, instead on the next line?

First I would advice against it. With my coding experience I would advice against putting any real functionality inside constructor. Normally constructor should be just for setting up the basic variables and environment correctly (like you are doing now). Because when you go to this road, you can add all sort of things to a constructor and it won't be the best for code structure. If you have multiple things to take care of in constructor you can separate them to some .init-function or so. But this is just MY opinion and experience on code organization.

If I remember "this" reference inside constructor correctly, You should be able to do it just like this:

```
addChildFunction = container.addChild.bind(container);
var a = new classA(addChildFunction);
var a2 = new classA(addChildFunction);
```

And just let the constructor receive the function as parameter:

```
function classA(addChild) {
    var texture = PIXI.Texture.fromImage("someImage");
    PIXI.extras.TilingSprite.call(this, texture, 224, 219);

    this.position.x = 0;
    this.position.y = 0;
    this.tilePosition.x = 0;
    this.tilePosition.y = 0;
    addChild(this);
}
```

Why I suggest using the .bind, is because it should give you more flexibility, if the container object changes in the future. If you pass the constructor container object, the container has to always have .addChild method, now and in the future (if something changes). Of course you can just pass the constructor the container object too, but if the container object changes in the future, you have to make sure the constructor handles it correctly.

Comment: I don't want to change the addChild() function, instead I wanted to associate the classes in some way that I would only need to instantiate the classA and simply add it once to the container, without the need to add 3 instances of classB for each classA. I wanted to do so because I intend to have 5 instances of classA, without the need to create 15 instances of classB, for instance.
Please let me know if things are clearer now...

Comment: I do not see the bigger issue you are trying to solve with this unfortunately, so I don't see actual reason for this. You could just wrap that inside a function, that makes the operation 5 times, but I assume that is not what you are after.

Is the purpose to have some bigger sprite consisting of 4 smaller individual images? If so you could just create it once and generate texture out of it. And use that texture to create them as individual objects and not as combination of classA and classBs.